# PHP OOP inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm facing a problem about inserting data into MySQL database.

```
public function insert($setTable, $setRow, $setValues) {

        $row = join(", ", $setRow);
        $values = join(", ", $setValues);       
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connect, "INSERT INTO $setTable ($row) VALUES ($values)");

        return $result;     
}

$currentLink = "test";
$st = 2;
$ide = 0;

$objMysql->insert("url", array("id_transaction", "id_user", "url"), array("$st", "$ide", "$currentLink"));
```

This is not working. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what errors do you get, did you try to output your insert query and run it in a mysql console/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Either `join` is not a function, you probably mean `implode`, or you created that function and it doesn't work, possibly causing the values to be injected without quotations.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is your code doesn't define `join()` nor does it define `$objMysql->insert()` -- your `insert()` is outside of the object so it is either incorrectly defined or your example is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `implode()` for rows / values also proper quotations.
using `join` doest not implode comma to `string`. i dont know where you use `$this->connect` or `$objMysql` but you've to make sure it is properly defined. so below functions will work properly.

```
function insert($setTable, $setRow, $setValues) {

        $row = implode(",", $setRow);
        $values = implode('","',$setValues);
        $prepareQuery = 'INSERT INTO '.$setTable.' ('.$row.') VALUES ("'.$values.'")';
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connect, $prepareQuery);
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: it's working now! yeah! so, the problem that i use Join instead implode. thank's you so much Mr. Norman. God Bless You!